# Triggering a Prefect workflow externally

Tags: workflow, airflow, prefect

I currently have a Prefect workflow running locally on an EC2 instance. I can trigger my workflow on localhost:8080 through the UI. Is there a way to trigger a Prefect workflow externally (say AWS Lambda) via REST API or some other way?

I know that Airflow supports an experimental REST API.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Prefect exposes a full GraphQL API that you can use to perform all types of actions, including the scheduling / triggering of a workflow.  [This blog post](https://medium.com/the-prefect-blog/event-driven-workflows-with-aws-lambda-2ef9d8cc8f1a) goes into more detail, and [here](https://github.com/cicdw/prefect-cloud-lambda) is some code for setting up an AWS Lambda function to trigger Prefect flow runs.

Comment: In theory, yes, but note that this requires an accessible API endpoint - one of the benefits of Cloud is that this endpoint is by default available to all services as long as you provide an authentication token.

Comment: Ah, I see. I kept looking for something similar to Airflow REST API where you can trigger a DAG run. But if I understood you right, for Prefect you'd need to incorporate Prefect library into your own service (Django, etc), right?

Comment: Prefect exposes a GraphQL API (also available in Prefect Server) but the Lambda function needs API access to the endpoint which can be a tricky networking problem, depending on your setup.

Comment: hey @chriswhite I am new to prefect and have setup prefect locally, is it possible to trigger my workflow externally using API or anything else ?  or workflow can be externally triggered only when prefect is on cloud ?

Comment: Hi @NeedToCodeAgain - yea you can, you'll need to make the API accessible by whatever external service needs to make the POST request

Answer (score 3):

> Yes through REST API you can trigger it using AWS Lambda, and can
> schedule AWS Lambda trigger using [CloudWatch Events Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html), it
> supports both fixed rate or crown expression scheduler