# Prefect how to wait for external dependency

Tags: python, etl, pipeline, prefect

I have a prefect flow that I want to run if and when a specific file appears. With something like Luigi you would create an ExternalTask that outputs that file and then impose a dependence on it. What is the standard pattern for this in Prefect?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options depending on your use case:

- create a waiting task: in this case, you can write a root task for your flow that waits for the external dependency / condition to be met, and then returns.  As long as the other tasks depend on this one, they won't run until this task completes.
- use the GraphQL API: both Prefect Server and Cloud have a fully featured GraphQL API for performing many common actions with flows and runs.  In this case, you can call `create_flow_run` whenever your external condition is met (possibly with `Parameter` values describing the condition) to create an ad-hoc run of your flow.  For more discussion of this pattern, check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256062/triggering-a-prefect-workflow-externally)